# Canvas - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I'm new to Canvas and was trying it out on Codepen. I keep getting the error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`

I've read a lot of similar questions about the same error on StackOverflow and tried some of the solutions provided but none of them seem to work.

Is this because the HTML is being loaded before JavaScript as some of the answers seem to suggest? Unfortunately, I don't think I can make that change on Codepen.

I've also tried wrapping it in `$( document ).ready(function() {});` using jQuery but that didn't work either.

Basically, I have this `<canvas>` element - `<canvas id="mycanvas" class="orangeback"></canvas>`
where I'm trying to create a rectangle and some text using the JavaScript below -

```
function doRed() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  id1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "purple";
  context.fillRect(10,10,60,60);

  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.font = "30px Arial";
  context.text = "Hello";
}
```

[Here's the link to my full code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anishsana/pattfqLq/)

It would be helpful if someone can point to me what's going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: **Typo:** `myCanvas` ==> `mycanvas`

Comment: (Also, not an error, but your `id1` variable already references that canvas, you don't need the `canvas` variable too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script had a typo error `myCanvas` should be  instead `mycanvas`.
You also query for canvas few times, you can minimize dom query using the result of `document.getElementById()` in a variable.

Example below:

```js
// cache result
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function doRed() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
  context.fillStyle = "purple";
  context.fillRect(10,10,60,60);    
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.font = "30px Arial";
  context.fillText= "Hello";
}

function doBlue() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

#div2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.orangeback {
  background-color: orange;
}

.yellowback {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blueback {
  background-color: blue;
}

.pinkback {
  background-color: pink;
}

canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Header</h1>
<canvas id="mycanvas" class="orangeback">
</canvas>
<input type="button" value="red" id="button2" onclick="doRed()">
<input type="button" value="blue" id="button3" onclick="doBlue()">
```

Comment: While you were at it, you could also have fixed the `context.text` typo and fixed the logic typo : draw only once, out of `doRed` or at least clear the canvas before drawing again ...

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your comment, I made an edit to my answer

Comment: Which doesn't work... `fillText` is a method.

Answer (score 1):

Your just had a typo. myCanvas to mycanvas should fix it. Attached the change in the snippet.

```js
function changeColor() {

  var id2 = document.getElementById("div2");

  id2.classList.add("pinkback");
}

function changeButton() {}

function doRed() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "purple";
  context.fillRect(10, 10, 60, 60);

  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.font = "30px Arial";
  context.text = "Hello";
}

function doBlue() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  id1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
}
#div2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.orangeback {
  background-color: orange;
}
.yellowback {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blueback {
  background-color: blue;
}
.pinkback {
  background-color: pink;
}
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Header</h1>
<canvas id="mycanvas" class="orangeback">
</canvas>
<canvas id="div2" class="yellowback">
</canvas>
<input type="button" value="change" id="button1" onclick="changeColor()">
<input type="button" value="red" id="button2" onclick="doRed()">
<input type="button" value="blue" id="button3" onclick="doBlue()">
<input type="button" value="button" id="button4" onclick="changeButton()">
```